# how to do process update Array on RecyclerViewAdapter with methods NotifyItemInsert() and NotifyItemDataChanged()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

> I am use RecyclerView and obitan Adapter and while accept the new ListArray I do process update the Adapter to on view  RecyclerView yet with methods notifyItemIndsert() or NotifyDataChanged():
> two methods 'll be do yet view on RecyclerView

```
dsArrayList.addAll( arraylistadd);
// size() -1 be the lastIndext element count position
recyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemInsert(dsArrayList.size()-1);

dsArrayList.addAll( arraylistadd);
recyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataChanged()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think notifyDataChanged is more useful in your case because notifyItemInsert is for single item inserted at some position.

Comment: Yes, I yet been knowed, That be hold likely. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Yes, to additation I to your friends, we can chat about development.